# Rate of the metric aggregated by label

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have a problem when trying to work with rate/irate functions in Prometheus.

I want to find a rate/irate of the metric, but aggregated by some of its labels.
For example, the metric is

```
application_errors_total{app="my_app_1", error_type="general_error"}
application_errors_total{app="my_app_1", error_type="specific_error"}
application_errors_total{app="my_app_2", error_type="general_error"}
application_errors_total{app="my_app_2", error_type="specific_error"}
```

And I would like to aggregate them to check the rate of all errors (both `general` and `specific`) for a given `app`, something like:

```
rate((sum(application_errors_total) by (app))[15s]) # incorrect promQL
```

Is it even possible with promQL? If `rate` would support aggregation (`rate(application_errors_total) by (app)`), then I would use it, but for some reason it does not.

I have tried:

- grouping in rate
- summing the rates (but this gives a false results in my case - if given `error_type` is present only once in a timespan, then it is not showing in the result)
- rating the sum (not working, as `rate` works on `range vector` and `sum` returns `instant vector`)

This blogpost https://www.metricfire.com/blog/understanding-the-prometheus-rate-function/ says, that it is possible to use `by` in a `rate`, but for some reason it does not work with our setup (Prometheus v2.33.4)

Answer (score 1):

As it was repeated [numerous](https://www.robustperception.io/rate-then-sum-never-sum-then-rate/) [times](https://%20https://groups.google.com/g/prometheus-users/c/ewWNOK10vWY), [again](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hands-on-infrastructure-monitoring/9781789612349/6323ea80-8748-43fc-8ee7-a6d88483f832.xhtml) and [again](https://%20https://www.section.io/blog/beware-prometheus-counters-that-do-not-begin-at-zero/) `rate` must be applied before `sum`.

Additionally both `rate` and `irate` require at least two samples in range vector to return anything. I doubt that you have a scrape interval of less then 8 seconds. So most likely you range selector is incorrect, and you need something bigger like `[30s]` or anything, but at least twice your scrape interval. And if you are planning to use it in Grafana you can use [`[$__rate_interval]`](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/add-template-variables/#__rate_interval) instead: Grafana will substitute best suited value itself.

Your query should look like

```
sum by (app) (rate(application_errors_total[30s]))
```

Comment: As I said - it does not work in my case. 
In my timespan (let's say 1hour) an error_type='specific_error' happens only once. And `general_error` happens once as well. `rate` from every one of them gives a constant `0`, as there is only one sample, so summing these two rates gives a sum of 0.
The example is very simple, in our case this metric has a lot of labels and `error_type` can have many possible values

Comment: @MateuszWicherski, ratio between panel time range and rate range can sometimes cause loss of small values on graph. Consider [this example](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=rate(caddy_http_requests_total{handler%3D%22rewrite%22}[30s])&g0.tab=0&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h&g0.end_input=2023-05-10%2004%3A06%3A07&g0.moment_input=2023-05-10%2004%3A06%3A07&g1.expr=rate(caddy_http_requests_total{handler%3D%22rewrite%22}[30s])&g1.tab=0&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=4h&g1.end_input=2023-05-10%2004%3A06%3A07&g1.moment_input=2023-05-10%2004%3A06%3A07)

Comment: @MateuszWicherski, is this similar to your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I have tested that as well. My problem is that I have metrics with several labels, that contain 'almost' unique information. Think of it as a label `process_id` which is added to each metric. There are many processes in the system, but if a given process has only one `error` type reported, then my `rate` metrics won't pick it up and I cannot set any alerting based on them.

Comment: @MateuszWicherski, if you need alerting `rate` is a wrong tool: it calculates per-second change of metric. If you simply want to alert whenever error in app happen use something like `sum by (app) (increase(application_errors_total[1m]))`. Where `1m` should be changed to `evaluation_interval` of your configuration.

Comment: `increase` is `0` as well in my case, so `sum` of `increases` is zero, regardless of the interval.

But tank you very much for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @MateuszWicherski, it shouldn't be. You doing something wrong with query, or don't see results due to visualization. Once again consider [example](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=increase(caddy_http_requests_total%7Bhandler%3D%22rewrite%22%7D%5B30s%5D)&g0.tab=0&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h&g0.end_input=2023-05-10%2004%3A06%3A07&g0.moment_input=2023-05-10%2004%3A06%3A07&g1.expr=increase(caddy_http_requests_total%7Bhandler%3D%22rewrite%22%7D%5B30s%5D)&g1.tab=0&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=4h&g1.end_input=2023-05-10%2004%3A06%3A07&g1.moment_input=2023-05-10%2004%3A06%3A07)